# Initialization order in java, contructor inside static block

Tags: java, constructor, static, initialization

Considering the standard java initialization order rules it is not clear to me why the following code

```
public class Foo {

    static { new Foo(); }

    static{ System.out.println("static code"); }

    { System.out.println("non static code"); }

    public Foo() { System.out.println("constructor"); }

    public static void main(String[] args) {}
}
```

outputs this:

```
non static code
constructor
static code
```

Comment: try to use debugger?

Comment: `static { new Foo(); }`, which invokes initialization (`System.out.println("non static code");`), then constructor (`System.out.println("constructor");`) and then just continues with static initialization (`System.out.println("static code");`)

Comment: What do you think will happen at `static { new Foo(); }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the static block will execute as soon as the class loader loaded the class. So, your first static block `static { new Foo(); }` execute first which further calls the constructor `new Foo();`. As per the java [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) the **non-static block will be copied to every constructor by the compiler** which means `System.out.println("non static code");` will be copied to the constructor `public Foo() { System.out.println("constructor"); }`. So, it will print `non static code` first then `constructor`. After the execution of first static block it will execute the second static block which prints the last `static code`.

After compilation your code looks similar to below code:

```
public class Foo {

    static { new Foo(); }

    static{ System.out.println("static code"); }

    public Foo() { 
       System.out.println("non static code");
       System.out.println("constructor"); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The JLS says that

- The static blocks and static variable initializations will be executed in program source code order when a class is initialized.
- The instance blocks and instance variable initializations will be executed in program source code order when an instance is initialized.  This happens *after* super instance initialization and *before* the constructor body is executed.

In your example, the first static creates an instance of `Foo`.  This cause the instance block for `Foo` to be executed *while* the first static block is being executed.  So, the sequence is:

1. The class is loaded
2. Static initialization for `Foo` is triggered
3. The first static block is executed which does a `new Foo()`.

   1. The instance block is executed - prints "non static code"
   2. The constructor is executed - prints "constructor"
4. The first static block finishes.
5. The second static block is executed - prints "static code".
6. The main method is called.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to refactor the code, do the following steps:

1) remove non-static initialisation block - the compiler puts it **before** the code in the actual constructor

```
public class Foo {

    static { new Foo(); }

    static{ System.out.println("static code"); }

    public Foo() {
        System.out.println("non static code");
        System.out.println("constructor");
     }

    public static void main(String[] args) {}
}
```

2) Join static initialisation blocks  - see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html):

> A class can have any number of static initialization blocks, and they
>   can appear anywhere in the class body. The runtime system guarantees
>   that static initialization blocks are called in the order that they
>   appear in the source code.

```
public class Foo {

    static {
        new Foo();
        System.out.println("static code");
     }

    public Foo() {
        System.out.println("non static code");
        System.out.println("constructor");
     }

    public static void main(String[] args) {}
}
```

3) From there, it should be obvious.